# How to add custom field to the Banner in Opencart CMS

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

Is there any way to add custom field to the Opencart default Banner, for example, for the big Owl Carousel on home page. It has only the title, link and image fields.

[image]

But I need to add custom field — for example, description.

Comment: Do you want to show content of this field, to visitors? or just want it for admin panel?

Comment: I want to manage this field in the admin panel and to output it on the frontend.

Comment: @irider It's really easy to add custom field on the banner management. You want to create one field on the banner table and add same structure code on the banner_form.tpl as well controller file and model file. when you successfully added field on admin side then add description field to frontend controller and see the output what you want.